# ERROR: open /home/ubuntu/.docker/buildx/activity/default: permission denied during docker build

Tags: docker

When I run a docker build command I get the following error:

```
ERROR: open /home/ubuntu/.docker/buildx/activity/default: permission denied
```

Note that I can execute `docker run hello-world` correctly without need for sudo.

A few more info:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-127:~/projects/$ ls -ld /home/ubuntu/.docker
drwx------ 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Dec 20 20:25 /home/ubuntu/.docker
ubuntu@ip-172-31-9-127:~/projects/$ groups ubuntu
ubuntu : ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev lxd netdev docker
```

I am using nvidia-docker2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying multiple solutions, I fixed by simply removing the file:

```
rm /home/ubuntu/.docker/buildx/activity/default
```